# On a trace condition for positive definite $2\times 2$ block matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory, positivity

Consider the following block matrix
$$
X = \begin{bmatrix} A & C \\ C^\top & B\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, and $C\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$.

**To Prove (or disprove)**: If $X$ is positive definite, i.e. $X>0$, then the following trace inequality holds
$$
\left[\mathrm{tr}(CC^\top)\right]^2< \mathrm{tr}(A^2)\mathrm{tr}(B^2).
$$

**Some comments.** Based on Theorem 2.3 of [Horn and Mathias. "Cauchy-Schwarz inequalities associated with positive semidefinite matrices." *Linear Algebra and Its Applications* 142 (1990): 63-82](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002437959090256C), I think it is possible to prove the previous fact if we replace strict inequalities with non-strict ones.

Comment: By $X>0$, I guess you mean positive definite, not positive entries.

Comment: Yes, I just edited the question in order to specify it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any unitarily invariant norm it can be shown that
\begin{equation*}
  \|X\| = \left\Vert 
    \begin{bmatrix}
      A & C\\
      C^* & B
    \end{bmatrix}
  \right\Vert \le \|A\| + \|B\|.
\end{equation*}
Thus, using the squared Frobenius norm on both sides and cancelling, we obtain
\begin{equation*}
  \|C\|_F^2 \le \|A\|_F\|B\|_F,
\end{equation*}
as desired.

Comment: But, the desired inequality is supposed to be sharp $<$ and not $\leq$. Am I right?

Comment: You are right, the OP asks for a strict inequality; I believe that it should be possible to make it strict without much trouble.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I'm wondering whether this still holds true with strict inequality.

Comment: Alternatively, we know that $X > 0$ iff there exists a contractive matrix $K$ (i.e., $\|K\| < 1$) such that $C=A^{1/2}KB^{1/2}$. Thus, we see that
\begin{equation*}
  \|C\|_F^2 = \mathrm{tr}(KAKB) < \text{rhs},
\end{equation*}
because $K$ is a strict contraction.

Comment: To get the strict inequality it is enough to apply the above solution to $X-\epsilon I$, where $\epsilon$ is small enough so as to make  $X-\epsilon I$ positive.